# xamarin c# work with two storyboards one for iPad and another for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard

Im developing an app and I want to use one storyboard for iPhone things and another for iPad thing, is it possible? where I have to define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Info.plist`, there is a key called `UIMainStoryboardFile`.

By default, that is assigned to `Main`, your Universal storyboard.

There are two more `string`-based keys available that can be added and assigned to different storyboards:

- `UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad`
- `UIMainStoryboardFile~iphone`

Info.plist example:

```
~~~
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
<string>iPadStoryboard</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile~iphone</key>
<string>iPhoneStoryboard</string>
~~~
```

Note: Make sure that the `UIViewController` in each of the Storyboards is set as `Is Initial View Controller` otherwise they will not show up by default when the app runs.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Open the properties of your iOS project.
Select under devices: Universal.
And you can select 2 storyboards, one for iPhone/iPod and one for iPad.